# How to avoid rounding to 0 in a double

Tags: java, math, double, rounding

I am struggling to get a double value to set to the right number.

In the following code:

```
double d =  (double) (500 / 1000) / 9000;
```

`d` is set to `0.0`.

I understand that doubles have limits and perhaps my problem is that I am exceeding the limits, but if I am is there a more appropriate way to store the result of this calculation?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change `(500 / 1000) / 9000` to `(500.0 / 1000) / 9000` in order to perform floating point division instead of `int` division. `500 / 1000` returns `0` while `500.0 / 1000` returns `0.5`.

Comment: @vaxquis Aha! I get it now, thank you!

Comment: @Aziz12 cheers, mate, glad to be of any help.

Answer (score 1):

You are computing with ints try with doubles instead:

```
double d = (500.0 / 1000.0) / 9000.0;
```

Comment: @Ceelos you can't trigger float division in Java using only integers. at least one of the operands has to be float - either literally, or by cast.

Comment: why cast an integer literal to float instead of using explicit float literal? that makes completely no sense to me, apart inducing a brain overhead in understanding what the code actually does.

Comment: @Caelos if you cast an int to a double than you are no longer working with an int. int / int = int not a double...

Comment: @Ceelos that was not what you started saying. I do understand the concept but there is information loss by doing a cast. Giving me a -1 because I disagree is a bit childish. [link](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.2.4)